# loading a shared library (cuda) in python via ctypes, cannot dynamically load

Tags: python, cuda, shared-libraries, ctypes

I have compiled my cuda script via the following command into a shared library :

```
nvcc --ptxas-options=-v --compiler-options '-fPIC' -o test_function.so mologram.cu
```

Then, in Python:

```
import ctypes
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./test_function.so')
```

Throws the following error message:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-02ce09d7f391> in <module>()
      2 from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer
      3 
----> 4 lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./test_function.so')


/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.pyc in LoadLibrary(self, name)
    438 
    439     def LoadLibrary(self, name):
--> 440         return self._dlltype(name)
    441 
    442 cdll = LibraryLoader(CDLL)

/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.pyc in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    360 
    361         if handle is None:
--> 362             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    363         else:
    364             self._handle = handle

OSError: ./test_function.so: cannot dynamically load executable
```

I have done similar scripts in the past and never encounter this error. I am baffled as to why this error message appears.

Any input appreciated

Comment: You can't load the shared library because it isn't a shared library...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have compiled my cuda script via the following command into a shared library
>
> `nvcc --ptxas-options=-v --compiler-options '-fPIC' -o test_function.so mologram.cu`

But you haven't. That only compiles `mologram.cu` to an object file. If you consult the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/#options-for-altering-compiler-linker-behavior), you will see that shared library compilation and linkage requires the `--shared` option. So

```
nvcc --ptxas-options=-v --compiler-options '-fPIC' --shared -o test_function.so mologram.cu
```

is probably what you want to do.